# Errno 30 when saving files from Jupyter notebooks using Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, file-io, jupyter-notebook, errno

Whenever I try to save a file from a Jupyter Notebook using Visual Studio Code, I get the error

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'filename'
```

is there a workaround to fix this? it doesn't happen when I use Jupyter notebooks normally, i.e. by accessing the localhost from the browser.

If it can help, I'm on Mac OsX Catalina.

EDIT: I'll add some basic code and the full error output.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['col1']=[1,2,3]

df.to_csv('test.csv')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b440cf2127b1> in <module>
      4 df['col1']=[1,2,3]
      5 
----> 6 df.to_csv('test.csv')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors)
   3165             decimal=decimal,
   3166         )
-> 3167         formatter.save()
   3168 
   3169         if path_or_buf is None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in save(self)
    188                 encoding=self.encoding,
    189                 errors=self.errors,
--> 190                 compression=dict(self.compression_args, method=self.compression),
    191             )
    192             close = True

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors)
    491         if encoding:
    492             # Encoding
--> 493             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline="")
    494         elif is_text:
    495             # No explicit encoding

OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'test.csv'
```

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment? Please try to switch to another environment and recreate the [Jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) file.

Comment: @JillCheng Yes I do. Is it ok if I switch to a copy of the current env? or should I create an empty env and re-install all the packages that I need?

Comment: You could try them all, creating a new environment is a better way, it will avoid interference from other factors.

Comment: @JillCheng tried both, nothing works unfortunately.

Comment: I can run the code you provided, please try the following suggestions: 1. Since the Jupyter function in VSCode is provided by a Python extension, it is recommended that you reinstall it. 2. Please disable other irrelevant extensions to avoid interference. 3. Please reinstall the Jupyter kernel "ipykernel" in the current environment. (pip install ipykernel)